# How to get those lines which have higher length among all the lines in the file using awk command

Tags: linux, awk

I want that line from the file which have highest length among all the lines using `awk` command.

Comment: What is your definition of "highest length"?  You say you want multiple lines, does that mean like "Top 5 highest length"?

Comment: I read it as “if there’s a tie, all the longest lines”

Comment: No I only want that "line which has higher length among all the lines"  and "if there is tie then all the longest line"

Comment: "higher" is a comparative word, and as such needs qualification. Do you mean "highest", i.e. the "longest line or joint-longest lines"?

Comment: @Shah, if the lines in the file were "ab", "cd", and "e", what is your expected result?

Comment: there are other solutions in that question that handle more than one line with max length... in gawk as well as other tools

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ if (length($0)>maxlength) { maxlength=length($0); longest_line=$0; } };
     END { print longest_line; }' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Check length of line (if no arguments passed to the `length` function it uses $0, the whole line).

Where length is greater than variable `x`, set `x` to the length.  And set variable `a` to the contents of the line.

Finally, on reaching end of file, print the contents of variable `a`.

```
awk 'length>x{x=length;a=$0}END{print a}' inputfile
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/JzUvvSTDrqK6whbCtE60VTGodfVzqS4oyswrUUis/f@/JCOzmAuI8vNyKrkSuUpSi0u48tO4cvLz0kHMnMy8VK60zLwULgA)